# Install Rviz in hydro

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Rviz in version hydro.  I keep getting: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-rviz
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191598/install-rviz-in-hydro/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-31**:
Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-09-01**:
I am running Ubuntu 13.10.  I see that ROS doesn't support anything newer than 13.04.  I assume that is the problem.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-01**:
If you are using 13.10 or 14.04 the recommended ROS distro is *Indigo*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To instanll rviz

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz
```

May be you need to check this [Configure your Ubuntu repositories](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu#hydro.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Configure_your_Ubuntu_repositories)

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0